# Reference to object properties

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of objects of type say Person, and I want to export Person records to an excel-sheet (I am using a proprietary excel component for VB.NET). Using a form with checkboxes the user can specify which Person properties should be exported.

Instead of having an enormous if-then-else tree where I check to see if each checkbox (corresponding to a property) has been checked, I have a data structure where for each property in Person I keep a boolean (checked/unchecked) and the name of the property as a string. I then use two for-loops like this:

```
For Each p As Person In Persons
    ...
    For Each item As ExportColumnData In ExportColumnTable
        ...
        If item.Checked Then
            ...
            Dim o As Object = CallByName(p, item.PropertyName, CallType.Get, Nothing)
            SaveValueToExcelSheet(o)
            ...
        End If
        ...
    Next
    ...
Next
```

However, this is not type-safe since I am using CallByName supplying PropertyName as a string. Is there a more elegant and type-safe way I can achieve the same thing? I need some way (other than a string) to reference the properties of these Person objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CallByName` function uses reflection to find and execute the property getter by string name, so you are right that it is unsafe in the sense that there will be no compile-time checking done to ensure that the properties by those names actually do exist in the `Person` type.

Unfortunately, short of a big `If/Else` block, or something similar, there is no "safe" way to do this in a way which will allow for compile-time type checking.  If you want it to check that at compile-time, you need to call the property by name directly in code, and if you are doing that, it will have to be in a big conditional block of some sort.

There are things you could do to minimize or shift the location of the ugliness.  For instance, you could create an enumeration of all the `Person` properties and add a method to the `Person` class which returns the property value given the enumeration item using a big `Select Case` block.  That would make the logic reusable but not really any less ugly.  Not only that, but doing it that way kind of puts the type-checking responsibility on your code, not the compiler.

Alternatively, you could, for instance, set the tag of each `CheckBox` control to a delegate which takes a `Person` object and returns the correct property value for that option from the given `Person` object.  Then, in the loop, you could just call the delegate in the tag to retrieve the value.  For instance, if you had a delegate like this:

```
Private Delegate Function GetPersonProperty(x As Person) As Object
```

Then you could set the `Tag` of the `CheckBox` controls like this:

```
chkFullName.Tag = New GetPersonProperty(Function(x As Person) x.FullName)
chkAge.Tag = New GetPersonProperty(Function(x As Person) x.Age)
```

Then, in your loop, you could invoke the delegate in the `Tag` to get the value, like this:

```
Dim myDelegate As GetPersonProperty = CType(item.Tag, GetPersonProperty)
Dim value As Object = myDelegate.Invoke(p)
```

But that's rather overly-complicated for such a simple task.

In the end, if the compile-time type checking is really important, I'd just bite the bullet and make the big conditional block.  If it's not really *that* important, I'd just stick with the reflection and put some decent exception handling in the code.

Comment: Compile-time checking isn't _that_ important, but as I have been working on the export functionality, the ugliness keeps annoying me. So I thought there must be a better way. How does that delegate you mentioned work? Can I have delegates for object properties?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is perfectly fine, as long as the contents in `ExportColumnData` are correct.  If these are computed dynamically at runtime, you're fine.

Otherwise, or alternatively, you can do the following: use [`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx) to get a list of `PropertyInfo` objects.  You can then use these instead of a mere String to extract property values in your loop:

```
Dim o As Object = item.PropertyInfo.GetValue(p, Nothing)
```

Comment: My problem is that the contents in ExportColumnData are not computed dynamically at runtime - it's simply a hardcoded string.

Comment: As I said, you could compute them at runtime by using `Type.GetProperties` (the answer by Dominic Kexel gives the actual detailed code to do this).  If that's not possible for some reason, you'll have to go with what Steven Doggart answered.

Answer (score 0):

You say you already have a class where you store the information about the properties of your Person class. You can use this to store the [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s as well.

Here's an example:

```
Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As Integer
End Class

Class ExportProperty
    Public Property [Property] As PropertyInfo
    Public Property Export As Boolean
End Class

Sub Main()
    '' Create a List(Of ExportProperty) from all public properties of Person
    Dim properties = GetType(Person).GetProperties() _
                                    .Select(Function(p) New ExportProperty With { .[Property] = p}) _
                                    .ToList()

    '' Say we want to export only the Age field                                     
    properties.Single(Function(p) p. [Property].Name = "Age").Export = True

    '' Create a person instance to export
    Dim pers = New Person With { .Name = "FooBar", .Age = 67 }  

    '' Only export the properties with Export = True
    For Each prop in properties.Where(Function(p) p.Export)

        '' Use the PropertyInfo.GetValue-method to get the value of the property
        '' 
        Console.WriteLine(prop.[Property].GetValue(pers, Nothing))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: While this is an interesting example of another way of using reflection, I fail to see how this solves the type-checking concern.  You're still searching for the property by string name using reflection.

Comment: @StevenDoggart It's a more elegant way to access the properties, and with little more work, it could be a lot faster than `CallByName` by using `Delegate.CreateDelegate` (if really needed). Also, since the properties are not accessed by a string, you can be sure that each property actually exists in the `Person` type.

Comment: I have thought about using `GetProperties()`, but I need a high degree of control over which properties are offered to the user for exporting. The way I see it, that's a bit difficult using `GetProperties()`.